# Capybara - Determine if selector count has changed

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am writing a test to confirm that hidden (Note: not destroyed. They are hidden using a boolean DB field) items no longer show up on my page. I know with Capybara I can use the following to confirm a selector's count:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('input', count: 12)
```

Is it possible to use similar logic to determine if the count has changed upon clicking a *hide* link?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
previous_count = page.all('input').size
click_on("Hide")
new_count = page.all('input').size
expect(new_count).to_not eq(previous_count)
```

or

```
expect do
  click_on("Hide")
end.to change { page.all('input').size }
```